# How do I list all names of the same group type?

Tags: views, 9, group

For a Group type (Birds), I tried to create a View in Drupal 9 to list all groups of that type, but I end up getting a group title entry for every node, for example this list.

- Birds groups

  - Hawks
  - Hawks
  - Hawks
  - Jays
  - Jays

I want it to be a group oriented list, and not group member oriented.

- Birds groups

  - Hawks
  - Jays

I'm only a view (an unformatted list) with group relationships. Groups aren't tied to users in any way.

What I tried to do is editing a view that shows nodes and change it to show groups by playing around with relationships from the *Advanced* settings section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to show groups, create a view that displays them.

Create a new view from /admin/structure/views/add - in *View settings*, *Show* **Group** *of type* **Birds**.

> [image: screenshot]